# Give us a site's API name in the list of a user's sites

Tags: feature-request, api-v2, associated

In the [/me/associated](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users) method, I get back a bunch of JSON - but the `api_site_parameter` name is nowhere to be found.

Why? It's kind of important. Could we have it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see any particular reason not to add it, but there are some workarounds you can use in the meantime:

- Build a cache of all site information with the site URL as the key, and then look up the `api_site_parameter` value (and associated information) that way.

or

- Use the fact that the domain name can be passed as a valid value for the `site` parameter, in all API routes that require it. EG: [`/2.2/answers?site=unix.stackexchange.com`](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers?site=unix.stackexchange.com)

  Clean up the returned `site_url` to fit, i.e.:

  ```
  var api_site = network_user.site_url.substring(
      network_user.site_url.indexOf("//") + 2,
      network_user.site_url.length - 1
  );
  ```

Comment: Really? I could pass `space.stackexchange.com` for site and it would get me results for Space Exploration?

Comment: Yes, so long as it's just the domain name. This is mentioned in the paragraph about the `site` parameter in [the documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), specifically "This parameter can be the **full domain name** (ie. "stackoverflow.com"), or a short form identified by `api_site_parameter` on the site object." (emphasis mine)

Comment: Awesome! So get the URL and rip out `http(s)://`. Simple!

Comment: Fwiw, the site_urls don't end with a `/` (maybe they used to). No big deal but the little substring snippet doesn't work verbatim like this.