# /associated should include user's display name and the api_site_parameter

Tags: feature-request, api, associated, sites

/associated should include api_site_parameter

The `/associated` routes return the `site_name` and `site_url` but not the `api_site_parameter`.

It would be useful if it did because `api_site_parameter` is the closest thing to a site id.

Also it would be good if the user's display name was returned in the response.

Comment: @TimStone, this is not an exact duplicate, since the OP also asks for user's name (which should be included).

Comment: @BrockAdams Ah, you're right. I feel like someone's asked for that before too, but I've reopened this now.

Comment: For completeness, part of this request is duplicated by [Give us a site's API name in the list of a user's sites](http://stackapps.com/q/4257)

Comment: @TimStone, I did a quick search for the name request but did not find it -- at least with the [associated] tag.